# SQL Server 2005 Run a stored procedure via SSIS using GETDATE() as a Parameter

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, ssis

I've been searching for an answer to this and I can't find it.  I want to set up an SSIS package using Visual Studio 2005 and SQL Server 2005 that will send today's date (GETDATE())as the parameter to a stored procedure.  I can find how to send a parameter, but not how to declare that parameter to be GETDATE().  Is this even possible?

Comment: If you really need to pass `GETDATE()` as a parameter to your stored procedure, you can just execute the SQL query it with `GETDATE()` instead of assign it to a parameter first

Comment: @Lamak, I actually have a couple of different stored procedures that all need today's date and I was hoping to just create one variable in the SSIS and pass it to all of them as they were run.  I just couldn't figure out how to do it for one to move on to the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a constantly evaluating time, like GETDATE() then, create a Variable in SSIS called `GetDate` with a Data Type of DateTime. Right click and on the properties window, check the EvaluateAsExpression = True and for the Expression, use `GETDATE()`

Now wire that variable up to the Execute SQL Task.

If you don't need this very moment, look at using one of the system scoped variables. The `ContainerStartTime` of the Execute SQL Task would probably suffice. My go to value is the `StartTime` as that's when the package started execution but you'll know best which one is right for you.

Answer (score 2):

One possible workaround to consider. You could make GETDATE() the default value for the parameter in the stored procedure and then call it without that parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProc 
    @InputDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
AS
...
```