# How can a step in an SSIS package check for the time?

Tags: ssis

The starting item in my Control Flow needs to be something that will check what time it is and set a variable. Is there an item in the Control flow items that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access your system variables. System::StartTime will be when the package started execution. If there is a significant amount of time between start of execution and the element that needs to evaluate the current time, you can look at the ContainerStartTime. If that isn't precise enough for you, look at using a script task.

[SQL Server 2005 Run a stored procedure via SSIS using GETDATE() as a Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334950/sql-server-2005-run-a-stored-procedure-via-ssis-using-getdate-as-a-parameter/9335021#9335021)